# Making a function for finding number of digits

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working on a CS50 course and I am trying to make a function that can give me a number of digits in a number that I put. For example number 10323 will be 5 digits. I wrote a code for this but it seems like it doesn't work for case above 10 digits. Can I know what is wrong with this code?

P.S: CS50 uses modified C language for beginners. The language may look a little different but I think its the math that is the problem here so there should be no much difficulty looking at my code?

```
int digit(int x) //function gives digit of a number
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
    return 0;    
    }
    else
    {
        int dig = 0;
        int n = 1;
        int y;
        do
        {
            y = x / n;
            dig ++;
            n = expo(10,dig);
        }   
        while (y < 0 || y >= 10);
        return dig;
    }
}
```

Comment: an alternative - convert number to a string, then take the length of the string

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I haven't learned about functions that gives me the length of strings yet. I only learned very basic for loop, do-while loop, while-loop with arithmetic and binary operations and I would only like to use those.

Comment: I think you can just use pointer arithmetic something like while (*x + (sizeof(int) * n)) != nil { digit += 1 } depends. Otherwise like you said bitwise operators. I like @OldProgrammer's answer. If your going to be writing c you should familiarize yourself with all things string including the functions.

Comment: @GregPrice I think you are right. I think its better to learn new things! Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You pass to your function an integer, that can have a max value of `2147483647`.. 10 digits. Try passing it `unsigned long` or unsigned long long`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thank you for the comment. I was thinking that it was because of the overflow. I will try unsigned long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't supply a definition for the function `expo()`, so it's not possible to say why the `digit()` function isn't working.

However, you're working with *int* variables. The specification of the size of the `int` type is implementation-dependent. Different compilers can have different sized ints. And even a given compiler can have different sizes depending on compilation options.

If the particular compiler your CS50 class is using has 16-bit ints (not likely these days but theoretically possible), those values will go from 0 (0x0000) up to 32767 (0x7FFF), and then wrap around to -32768 (0x8000) and up to 01 (0xFFFF). So in that case, your `digit` function would only handle part of the range up to 5 decimal digits.

If your compiler using 32-bit ints, then your ints would go from 0 (0x00000000) up to 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF), then wrap around to -2147483648 (0x80000000) and up to -1 (0xFFFFFFFF), thus limited to part of the 10-bit range.

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you have 32-bit ints.

You can get an extra bit by using the type `unsigned int` everywhere that you are saying `int`. But basically you're going to be limited by the compiler and the implementation.

If you want to get the number of decimal digits in much larger values, you would be well advised to use a string input rather than a numeric input. Then you would just look at the length of the string. For extra credit, you might also strip off leading 0's, maybe drop a leading plus sign, maybe drop commas in the string. And it would be nice to recognize invalid strings with unexpected non-numeric characters. But basically all of this depends on learning those string functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that I did define the expo() as a function that does the exponent. This answer helped a lot thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
"while(input>0)
    {
        input=input/10;
        variable++;
    }
    printf("%i\n",variable);"
```

link an input to this.

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's code? How does your code work with 10+ digit numbers?